# ReactJS 404 error after refreshing the page in server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, webserver

I have deployed a reactjs web application and in the local server, it works perfectly but after deployment on the server, it showed a 404 error when I refresh any page.

Comment: Way more information needed. What exactly did you deploy to the server? Are you using webpack/build? What type of server are you deploying to?

Comment: Can you describe what router component you currently use? If you are using react-router-dom with Browse Router, make sure the server has no conflict on URI with the client-side. Otherwise, you might need to resolve this conflict on the server-side or just change the Browser Router to Hash Router

Answer (score 2):

Mr. @KieranQuinn and @HonghaiMei take love.
Thanks to everyone who help me and who try to help me.
The issue is solved by using **HashRouter** instead of **Browserrouter**.